# Does the full header of the email taken from gmail inbox always contain a <return path> tag?

Tags: google-apps-script

When an email is sent from one gmail account to another gmail account and upon extracting the full headers of the same email received by the recipient in his inbox, here are my two critical questions.

1. Do the header tags of email taken from the recipients inbox always
   contain a Return Path tag?
2. What other tags need to be definitely present to ascertain the email to be genuine and not tampered?
3. What does it mean when the content within the  tag is different from the content on the actual subject line?

Example: Subject tag indicates  but the actual subject on the gmail message indicates Hello!

Any response from the google team is most appreciated in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `Return-path` header field is mandatory. Is is set by the last SMTP server to handle the message. See [RFC 5321](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt) for the full, gory detail. [This site](https://www.postmastery.com/blog/about-the-return-path-header/) also has a pretty good plainer English explanation.

An important caveat, as noted in the RFC:

> It is possible for the mailbox in the return path to be different
>   from the actual sender's mailbox, for example, if error responses are 
>   to be delivered to a special error handling mailbox rather than to
>   the message sender.  When mailing lists are involved, this
>   arrangement is common and useful as a means of directing errors to
>   the list maintainer rather than the message originator.

So the `Return-path` header on isn't the best option for verifying email authenticity. If you're looking for methods of verifying authenticity & detecting tampering, look into [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) & [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC). In short:

- **SPF** provides verification that the email originates from a server authorised to send email on behalf of a given domain
- **DKIM** uses message signing to detect message tampering & verify that the email was indeed sent from the domain it claims
- **DMARC** leverages both SPF & DKIM & additionally verifies that the domains involved in all of these processes & in the SMPT chain are all in alignment

Comment: Thank you Dean! I had one more question along the same lines.